# jOOQ - Return tuple of fields from "then" in "when" query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I use jOOQ with PostgreSQL and I'm trying to create a select query with multiple counts using `CASE WHEN`. Because it's important to count only unique records, I also use `DISTINCT` statement. Sometimes I need to distinct on multiple columns, which is perfectly correct in SQL syntax, but I can't figure out how to do it in jOOQ.

I use `CASE` for counting because I also have queries with more conditions. I simplified these examples for convenience.

Example working SQL:

```
select
   count(distinct (case when "UserID" = 11 then "CategoryID" end)) as "UserCatNum",
   count(distinct (case when "UserID" = 11 then ("CategoryID", "PageID") end)) as "UserPageNum"
from data_table
```

When I try with just one field, it works:

```
query.addSelect(
    DSL.countDistinct(
        DSL.when(DSL.condition(Operator.AND, conditions), CATEGORY_ID)
    ).as("UserCatNum")
);
```

But when I try something like this:

```
query.addSelect(
    DSL.countDistinct(
        DSL.when(DSL.condition(Operator.AND, conditions),
        DSL.row(CATEGORY_ID, PAGE_ID))
    ).as("UserPageNum")
);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot interpret argument of type class org.jooq.impl.RowImpl as a Field: ("data_table"."CategoryID", "data_table"."PageID")
```

I tried `DSL.row()` because I saw a similar usage with `IN` statements. I also tried replacing this with `DSL.select()`, but it doesn't work, neither Arrays and Lists.

For now I resolved this by writing a small function:

```
private Field<Object> tupleField(Field... fields) {
    String tuple = Arrays.stream(fields)
        .map(f -> f.getQualifiedName().quotedName().toString())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    return DSL.field("(" + tuple + ")");
}
```

But it would be nice to know how to do this using jOOQ's API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A row value expression (e.g. [`org.jooq.Row2`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Row2.html)) can be converted to an ordinary column expression ([`org.jooq.Field`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html)) by using the experimental [`DSL.rowField()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#rowField-org.jooq.Row2-) methods.

This will then work in the API, and might generate the appropriate expected SQL, but as of jOOQ 3.11 / 3.12, this support is still quite experimental and not well tested. It might well be that row fields, when used in expressions like the `CASE` expression, will not be properly fetched from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the SQL works is because `("CategoryID", "PageID")` is interpreted as a *tuple* and Postgres can count those distinctly.  Otherwise, `count(distinct)` does not take multiple expressions.

I do not know how to create tuples in JOOQ.  However, you can probably do some string concatenation to result in `"CategoryID" || ':' || "PageID"` and get the result you want.

Comment: I'm aware that I can use plain SQL in jOOQ, but I want to avoid this as much as possible. I thought `DSL.row()` creates tuples, but apparently `DSL.when()` doesn't want to accept this as a field.